# Xilinx Zynq peripheral drivers

Tags: driver, xilinx, zynq

I have started to develop software for the ZYNQ 7020 SoC from Xilinx. I have finished several tutorials and I have found that whenever I use some predefined block in the PL (for example GPIO controller) then associated software driver for that peripheral is automatically generated. Does anybody know whether this is true only for the predefined blocks or also for user developed blocks? Thanks.

I have found in my opinion useful [document](https://www.so-logic.net/en/knowledgebase/fpga_universe/tutorials/Basic_ESD_Tutorial) regarding the process of custom IP block drivers development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools can't automatically write your driver, but if you package your IP block and driver in the right format you can do the same type of thing. Look here for some more info on how to do that: [Is there a way to pass a design parameter from a custom IP to software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990095/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-design-parameter-from-a-custom-ip-to-software)

Comment: Justin N, thank you very much for your answer. Do I understand correctly that in case I develop my IP block I need to define code of its driver and also the tcl script which will interract with the Vitis during platform project generation? Thanks.

Comment: @Steve Yes. You'll also need to package up your HDL IP core using the IP packager in the GUI if you aren't already.

Comment: Thanks, Justin N. Can you recommend me any information resource? I have inspected the UG1138 which is mentioned in the link. Unfortunately it is too general for me. I would appreciate some example.

Comment: @Steve Take a look at Xilinx's cores and drivers for reference. For example, the GPIO core at data\ip\xilinx\axi_gpio_v2_0 and driver data\embeddedsw\XilinxProcessorIPLib\drivers\gpio_v4_4\data (directories are under your Xilinx install directory; version numbers might be different).